# what am i doing wrong with this aluminum sheet?

Tags: rendering

I already asked this question once, but still nothing helps. is there anyone here who knows a solution? :(
I would like to get the aluminum effect on the ramp as in the second picture below. However, I'm doing something wrong. i tried different ways and this is the last one. I used hdri clarens midday and stage lighting. Maybe it's a lighting issue? I would like it to look like a realistic sheet of aluminum.
I moved the stripes on the color ramp. I changed the lighting, but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What am I doing wrong with this aluminum?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293991/what-am-i-doing-wrong-with-this-aluminum)

Comment: Yes, i delete this one because still No help :(

Comment: Do you know how to help???

Comment: You could try asking for guidance on Blenderartists.org forums. Blender Stack Exchange is a great resource, but this question seems a bit too opinion based for it. You should at least edit the question and form it in a more specific manner. What "different ways" have you tired? Why specifically are you unhappy with the result? At the moment the biggest difference between your reference and result seems to be the geometry - reference has rounded edges, why are you concerned about the shader?

Comment: ok i will try there. I would like mine to look more realistic. mine is matte, even if I change it in the color ramp then alvo is still matte or reflects elements from hdri :(

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: I think you probably need less roughness and to light the object from multiple angles

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's not like yours looks bad.  It just has a different finish.

[image]

A kind of lightly worn look, which you defined here:

[image]

The color ramp will move the boundaries around, but the pattern comes from the textures you mixed together.  If you don't want that you can replace it with something else.

You could use a streaky texture for a brushed finish, but if you want it smooth like the reference shots you need to just unplug and use a flat number, probably in the .2 to .4 range or something.

The rest comes down to lighting.

[image]

Here's a very simple material, this was produced with two very large area lights and no hdri.  The object basically only looks good from this angle, if that gives you any idea.  A highly reflective metallic object only reflects the lights and any background back into the camera.